# EmberJS Using Component in Different Context

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bootstrap-switch

I am trying to use a different library `bootstrap-switch` from within EmberJS.

I added the following with `.on('didInsertElement')`:

```
$(toggleTag).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
      this.sendAction('updateAction', state);
});
```

However, when this event is invoked, the context of `this` will return `object` for the html element `toggleTag`. Instead, I need access to the `component` for `this`.

What is the recommended way of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6 use [fat arrows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and inherit the context of the parent (if you're using ember-cli, this is recomended):

```
$(toggleTag).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event, state) => {
  this.sendAction('updateAction', state);
});
```

In ES5 either use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the function context:

```
$(toggleTag).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state){
  this.sendAction('updateAction', state);
}.bind(this));
```

Or save the context:

```
var that = this;
$(toggleTag).on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state){
  that.sendAction('updateAction', state);
});
```